Manhua about a guy that has a system and can travel to different time lines or dimensions
He might have had blue hair. Every time he went to a new world, his abilities reset and he had to spend points to gain them back. I remember in one of the worlds, he was a martial artist that was fighting against guns and the Westerners, and he punched a rocket, showing martial arts is better. They made statues of him and put his name down in the history books.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

I dont really remember

Did he appear Japanese? Caucasian? African? Was his hair long? Short? Braided? Mohawk? Did he get his system as a result of reincarnation? Superpowers? Demonic possession? VR world?

Chinese or Japanese short to medium hair i don't really remember about how he got the system.
